# Blazor File Upload Issues

Tags: exception, upload, blazor, asp.net-core-6.0, blazorinputfile

I am writing my first Blazor (Server Side) app and have run into a big issue with errors when trying to upload files. To be clear it works for some people but not for others. Everyone is using the same browser but people are in different locations at my work, connected via WAN.

Here is the Exception that is being thrown :

> An error occurred while reading the remote stream: TypeError:
> r.arrayBuffer is not a function

It is being thrown by

> CopyToAsync(fs)

I have tried Microsoft own code, literally, but still getting an exception.

```
await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
await browserFile.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
```

I separated the code to find where the exception was being thrown

```
using var input = file.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize);
using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Create);
input.CopyToAsync(fs);
```

I have even tried reading directly to a MemoryStream which Microsoft warns against, but in all cases there is the same exception when CopyToAsync() is called.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated. Any workarounds would be appreciated as well.

Comment: It looks like this is Blazor Server - is that correct? If so, then what your code is doing is trying to stream the file upload over the JSInterop/SignalR connection from the client - this may be a problem because it will flood that connection as it streams the data. That doesn't mean it will always fail, but it does mean it is more likely to fail, especially with large files. Unfortunately, the Blazor team have not provided an out-of-the-box way to do this without using the same SignalR stream as the UI and their documentation steers you towards doing exactly what you have here.

Comment: Thank you Mister Magoo. Yes, this Blazor Server. How would you handle this problem? Do you have a recommendation about a different way to do this?

Comment: Are there any configuration changes that you would suggest to reduce the chances of failure?

Comment: I don't have a fully formed answer, but ideally you upload the files from the browser directly to an api on the server - usually through a form post with the files attached to the form - Blazor has no built-in support for this because they are happy to do it the way you are . You can probably find a library already built but I don't have any specific recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API endpoint it not publicly available over the internet so I could not send the upload to it directly.  I was thinking about using MCV to get the file uploaded but since the MVC is within the same project as Blazor, my concern is that it will also go over a SignalR connection.

Comment: You could try tweaking the signalR settings for maximum messages size, it may be using a different value makes it more reliable on your network